# Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server. django tutorial

Tags: python, html, django

I was following a tutorial to build social media using Django at this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-social-media-website-with-django-part-5-feed-app-templates-66ddad5420ca

I followed all the code as it says but once I'm done, I ran "python manage.py runserver" in the terminal, it gave me the Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server. I'm not sure why as I'm new to Django.

you can find my code here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GSIK6ZoAsuOude3m6QKbiHhV8iAOZ7um?usp=sharing

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What URL were you trying to access?

Comment: I was just using the local server url provided by my command prompt when I run the manage.py file. I type in python manage.py runserver in the command prompt

Comment: What URL were you trying to access?  Show us exactly what you typed in your browser.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is the url address.